# captureStillImageAsyncronouslyFromConnection - Cannot convert the expression's type

Tags: ios, swift, closures, avfoundation

I'm fresh to Swift so I'm still ironing out some of the finer details; I apologize if I'm missing something obvious. I've browsed around and found solutions to similar errors in different method calls, but those answers haven't helped me in figuring out my issue. I make this call

```
    captureOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(port) {
        (imageDataSampleBuffer: CMSampleBufferRef?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        // TODO
    }
```

which is flagged with the following error:

`Cannot convert the expression's type '(@lvalue AVCaptureInputPort, (CMSampleBufferRef?, NSError?) -> Void)' to type 'AVCaptureConnection!'`

The issue is clearly with my closure. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue is clearly with my closure

Actually, no. The issue is clearly with `port`. This argument is supposed to be an AVCaptureConnection - but you are supplying an AVCaptureInputPort instead.

Comment: Haha, whoops. I got the port, jumped the gun and completely forgot to add a connection. I ran into some early issues with supplying the closure which segued into my thinking that it was the problem here. Thanks for pointing that out!